# Prove or disprove the lemma regarding finite iterations that leads to a palindromic number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, palindrome

> Suppose there is a natural number $N$. Let us reverse the digits of $N$. Now let us add both the numbers e.g. if $N=98$ then add $98$ and $89$. Theorem says that if we keep doing this finite number of times then we will get a natural number that is also palindrome.

Examples:

$1.$ Consider $N=19$ Now add $19$ and $91$ to get the result as $100$ Now add $100$ and $001$ to get the result and the palindrome number $101$

$2.$ Consider $N=9$ Now add $09$ and $90$ to get the result and the palindrome number as $99$

$3.$ Consider $N=99$ then repeat the steps for a few times to get the result and the palindrome number $79497$

Is this lemma true$?$ I tried considering it for two digit numbers $10a+b$ Reversing the digits and adding them will yield $11a+11b$ which is a symmetric function in $a$ and $b$. I am not able to prove it for two digit numbers let alone a generalized case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have found that, if you start with $N=196$, the iteration doesn't seem to ever stop. (Did something like 61,000 iterations, the numbers there have >25,000 digits and never got a palindrome.) I'd say that the "lemma"/"theorem" is likely false. (In which case please don't call it a "lemma" or a "theorem" - reserve those terms for proven statements.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop i tried for $N=563$ (reverse of number of days in a year) and I got the result $$88555588$$

Comment: Yes, $196$ is notorious as the first number for which the behavior of the iteration is not known.

Comment: @StinkingBishop i guess it should be true for $196$ also maybe after a very long process

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is an unsolved problem, damn

Comment: @GerryMyerson but is there a proof stating that eventually most of them will form a palindrome

Comment: I don't know, but have a look at the Wikipedia page and the links given there to see what's known.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  i did have a look but couldnt found a proof

Comment: Then there may not be one. I don't know.

Comment: See also http://jasondoucette.com/worldrecords.html and https://oeis.org/A023108